# Why does JMenu not render correctly when using System L&F?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, look-and-feel, jmenu

## Bug Report

This has been confirmed as a bug. You can track it here:

https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8258934

## Background

- There's no other code running besides what I've posted in the MCVE; there are no other JVMs active when running this program (though I don't believe that should matter).
- I do not have any programs installed which customizes the UI of my system.

**Target Environment**

```
Java 1.8.0_201
Windows 10 Home Edition
```

**Tested JDKs**

- JDK 8 to JDK 15

**Tested by third party**

- [George Z.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65387329/why-does-jmenu-not-render-correctly-when-using-system-lf#comment115601687_65387329) - Windows 7 - **Can reproduce bug**
- [David Kroukamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65387329/why-does-jmenu-not-render-correctly-when-using-system-lf#comment115602651_65387329) - Windows 10, JDK 10 - **Can reproduce bug**
- [camickr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65387329/why-does-jmenu-not-render-correctly-when-using-system-lf#comment115602024_65387329) - Windows 10, JDK 11 - **Can reproduce bug**
- Canvas (Discord) - Windows 10 - **Can reproduce bug**
- Pawnee (Discord) - macOS Catalina 10.15.7, JDK 15 - ***Unable to reproduce bug***

---

## MCVE

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Demo::launchUI);
    }

    private static void launchUI() {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JMenuItem report = new JMenuItem("Report");
        JMenu newMenu = new JMenu("New...");
        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        JMenuBar bar = new JMenuBar();

        newMenu.add(report);
        fileMenu.add(newMenu);
        bar.add(fileMenu);
        frame.setJMenuBar(bar);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

---

## Reproduction Steps

1. Run the MCVE
2. Click through the menus
3. Resize the window
4. Click through the menus again

---

## MCVE Results

Windows 10 machine targeting JDK 11 (though similar results on all tested major Java distributions):

[image]

- Menus give different render results before & after resizing the window
- There's overlap of the highlighting - the highlight of "New..." bleeds into the "Report" menu item.

---

- Sometimes the arrow of "New..." will get overlapped by "Report" as shown below.

**Windows 7** - image by [George Z](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6579265/george-z)

[image]

**Windows 10, JDK** - image by Canvas (Discord)

[image]

---

## New Findings

The highlight bug does not appear if part of the "Report" menu item is outside of the windows bounds.

[image]

This was achieved by updating the popout offset for menus:

```
// apply this before creating any components
UIManager.put("Menu.menuPopupOffsetX", 20);
UIManager.put("Menu.menuPopupOffsetY", 20);
```

---

## Works on...

- **macOS Catalina 10.15.7** - image by Pawnee (Discord)

[image]

---

## Question

Does `JMenu` work properly with System L&F, and if so, what am I missing to get proper results? (No extra spacing, no highlights bleeding into other components)

Comment: [Same thing happens in Windows 7 as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wzaf1.png)

Comment: Works OK for me on Windows 10 using JDK 11.

Comment: Same as OP and I have window 10, jdk1.8.0_261.

Comment: I see the same results as you with your updated code. I don't see any problem with your code. I also downloaded the `MenuLookDemo` code from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Menus](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html), changed the code to use System LAF and get the same results.  so I would suggest this is a LAF bug.

Comment: @GeorgeZ.What version of Java are you using?

Comment: This is probably because of different types of popups used: lightweight versus heavyweight. It seems like heavyweight popups work correctly whereas lightweight don't.

Comment: @AlexeyIvanov What heavyweight component is being used though? These are all lightweight Swing components

Comment: @Vince Menu items are rendered in `Popup`s. Take a look at [`PopupFactory.getPopup`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/PopupFactory.html#getPopup(java.awt.Component,java.awt.Component,int,int,boolean)): “`isHeavyWeightPopup` specifies if the `Popup` will be heavyweight. Lightweight `Popup` windows are more efficient than heavyweight (native peer) windows…”. A lightweight popup uses a `JComponent` which is rendered in `JLayeredPane` whereas a heavyweight popup uses a `Window` that creates a _native window_.

Comment: @AlexeyIvanov `JMenu` is using a `JPopupMenu`, which is a `JComponent`, https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.desktop/share/classes/javax/swing/JMenu.java#L530-L537

Comment: @Vince Look further: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/ac2dfe45d1b7fb9b99b0ba1402189de1791319b8/src/java.desktop/share/classes/javax/swing/JPopupMenu.java#L852-L878 Try calling [**`JPopupMenu.setLightWeightPopupEnabled`**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JPopupMenu.html#setLightWeightPopupEnabled(boolean)) to disable lightweight popups: `fileMenu.getPopupMenu().setLightWeightPopupEnabled(false); newMenu.getPopupMenu().setLightWeightPopupEnabled(false);`

Comment: @AlexeyIvanov Setting it to `false` would cause it to use a heavyweight component, which would mix lightweight & heavyweight. The container is lightweight, so shouldnt the popup also be lightweight?

Comment: @Vince Did you try it? I explained above that a heavyweight popup is used automatically if it doesn't fit inside the `JFrame` bounds. No mixing will occur because heavyweight popups aren't added into `JFrame` hierarchy, they are native windows which are displayed on top of your frame and on top of other popups for that matter. Yet lightweight popups are added into `JLayeredPane` for rendering, so the lightweight popups become part of component hierarchy.